# How to place Glass over the rock?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I am trying to responsive the glass with rock using some custom javascript and TailwindCss. I need to place the glass over the rock on all breakpoints.

Glass should be place like this:
[image]

> Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    </head>
    
        <body>       
            <div>
                <div class="text-center relative">
                    <div class="mx-auto w-48 h-auto mb-2 relative mb-4 shadow-inset ">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qjqqmQ0/glass-7-web-removebg-preview-2.png" class="glass_icon object-cover w-full h-96" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        <script>
            const body = document.querySelector("body");
            body.style.background = `url('https://harvest-selection.netlify.app/assets/background/In-Woods.gif') no-repeat fixed 50% 100%`;
    
            body.style.cssText += `background-size: cover;height:100vh`;
        </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood it correctly. Do you think so?

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
body > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/qjqqmQ0/glass-7-web-removebg-preview-2.png) no-repeat center/40%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img src="https://harvest-selection.netlify.app/assets/background/In-Woods.gif">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .glass{
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/qjqqmQ0/glass-7-web-removebg-preview-2.png") 43% 180px no-repeat, url("https://harvest-selection.netlify.app/assets/background/In-Woods.gif") left top no-repeat;
  padding: 15px;
  background-size: 100px, 100%;
height: 400px;
}
```

```html
     <div>
       <div class="text-center relative">
         <div class="glass">
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```